# Using N channel MOSFET as switch

Tags: batteries, switches

I have many N-channel MOSFET and i want to know is there a way to use as an alternative of P-channel **(Q1)** in this circuit?

This circuit is responsible of switch between battery and power source.
[image]

Comment: Depending on the application you could just use a diode and omit the FET entirely. If you can live with the power dissipated in the diode when running on battery power.

Comment: @Unimportant but voltage drop is important

Comment: You need to build yourself a charge pump or similar to provide the positive Vgs needed, and some circuitry to level shift your gate signal.